# MYSQL custom query order by search token issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Right now i'm building a custom query using php and mySql. Say I've a string **Hello this is me**. For this

```
select distinct(user_primary.id) as id 
from user_primary, 
user_sec, 
user_location, 
user_ind_cat 
where 
( 
 user_primary.status != 3 
 and 
 (
  user_primary.id = user_sec.job_id
 ) 
 and 
 (
  user_primary.id = user_ind_cat.job_id
 )
) 
and 
( 
 (
  user_primary.name like "%Hello%"
 ) 
 or 
 (
  user_primary.name like "%this%"
 ) 
 or 
 (
  user_primary.name like "%is%"
 ) 
 or 
 (
  user_primary.name like "%me%"
 ) 
 and 
 (
  user_primary.name like "%Hello this is me%"
 )
) 
and 
(
 user_primary.login <= 1415426357
) 
limit 0, 150
```

So far it was working fine until recently I've found a issue. Whenever I ran this kind of query it generates results contains user's with full name like the search token and other matching tokens generated from search token. But the actual row which has perfect match with provided token "Hello this is me" is not showing in top.

Let me explain the results if i ran current query,

1. "Hello how are you"
2. "this is nixon"
3. "Hello this is me"
4. "oh hello there"
5. "I'm me"
6. "hello you there"

I want to show the actual result in the top, so the results will be look like this,

1. "Hello this is me"
2. "Hello how are you"
3. "this is nixon"
4. "oh hello there"
5. "I'm me"
6. "hello you there"

Can anyone please tell me what's the problem here? Or should I remove or add the query?

Thanks in advance,

Nixon

Comment: Is your search token not showing at all or is it just not showing at the top of the result-list?

Comment: @Benni it's not showing at the top of the result-list.

Comment: Remove Table `user_Location` from your query, it is not used or joined...

Comment: Is the part `and ( user_primary.name like "%Hello this is me%" )` really connected with `and`? Not `or` as well?

Comment: Removing `user_location` won't give the solutions. Beside this query is generated dynamically, which means in some point the application will create a query for joining `user_location`.

Comment: It was using or. I changed the query to make sure that it will find the actual user who has the full name like the tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a FULL TEXT INDEX!

```
 ALTER TABLE `user_primary` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (`name`);
```

MySQL has now created a fuzzier search index for text than your chain of OR's.   So, part of your query will look like:

```
 SELECT name, MATCH(name) AGAINST ('Hello this is me') as confidence 
     FROM user_primary
     WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('Hello this is me')
     ORDER BY confidence DESC
```

The better the match, the higher `confidence` will be, so "Hello this is me" should be on top.

This might be your query, cleaned up and untested:

```
select distinct(user_primary.id) as id , MATCH(name) AGAINST ('Hello this is me') as confidence
from user_primary, user_sec, user_location, user_ind_cat 
WHERE 
 user_primary.status != 3 
 and user_primary.id = user_sec.job_id 
 and user_primary.id = user_ind_cat.job_id
 and MATCH(name) AGAINST ('Hello this is me')
 and  user_primary.login <= 1415426357
ORDER BY confidence DESC
limit 0, 150
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wish the OP would come back and mark it as "answered", if it answered the question.

Comment: @mainstreetmark I was busy on other problems, that's why i didn't see this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Match-score and sort by it:

```
select distinct(user_primary.id) as id,

CASE user_primary.name 
  WHEN user_primary.name like "%Hello this is me%" THEN 100
  WHEN user_primary.name like "%Hello%" THEN 50
  WHEN user_primary.name like "%this%" THEN 40
  WHEN user_primary.name like "%is%" THEN 30
  WHEN user_primary.name like "%me%" THEN 10
  ELSE 0
END as sortScore


from user_primary, 
user_sec, 
-- user_location, 
user_ind_cat 
where 
user_primary.status != 3 
and user_primary.id = user_sec.job_id
and user_primary.id = user_ind_cat.job_id 
and 
( 
 user_primary.name like "%Hello this is me%"
  or user_primary.name like "%Hello%"
  or user_primary.name like "%this%"
  or user_primary.name like "%is%"
  or user_primary.name like "%me%"
)
and user_primary.login <= 1415426357
order by sortScore
limit 0, 150
```